# Converting SelectedItems to IEnumerable<MyType>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, gridview, datacontext

I'm using a GridView with the SelectionMode set to Multiple. I select a few items, then on my button click event, I want to process those selected items.

I'm able to grab the collection of these items with the GridView.SelectedItems property, and treat this as a generic list. I want to be able to treat this as a list of the type of underlying objects within that list.

I can validate *all* the items in the list are of the correct type:

```
if(items.Any(item => !(item is MyType))) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid list of items");
```

But what I'm unable to do is treat that list as anything other than a list of objects. For example:

```
items is IList<object> = true
items is IEnumerable<object> = true;
```

however

```
items is IList<MyType> = false
items is IEnumerable<MyType> = false
```

such that something like `return (items as List<MyType>)` fails

Short of enumerating the list and creating a new one of type `MyType` I'm at a loss.

```
var myItems = new List<MyItem>(items.Count);
foreach (var item in items)
{
    myItems.Add(item as MyItem);
}
```

any tips?

Comment: Please show the code where you create items as a list<MyType> from the selecteditems.

Comment: @N4TKD I don't see how it's helpful, but I added the code. It's very trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `list.Cast<MyType>()` will throw exception if any single element is not of given type
- `list.OfType<MyType>()` will filter out by give type

Also:

- `list.Count() != list.OfType<MyType>()` will iterate sequence twice if it doesn't implement `IList`, i.e. is pure enumerator and not List or Array

Answer (score 4):

try

```
items.Cast<MyType>()
```